# C: qsort doesn't seem to work with unsigned long

Tags: c, unsigned, qsort

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the following example? I took it from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) and replaced `int` by `unsigned long`. I also changed the `cmpfunc` to properly handle `unsigned long`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  if(*(unsigned long*)a - *(unsigned long*)b < 0){
    return -1;
  }

  if(*(unsigned long*)a - *(unsigned long*)b > 0){
    return 1;
  }

  if(*(unsigned long*)a - *(unsigned long*)b == 0){
    return 0;
  }
}

int main()
{
   int n;

   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");

   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) 
   {
      printf("%lu ", values[n]);
   }

   qsort(values, 5, sizeof(unsigned long), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");

   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) 
   {   
      printf("%lu ", values[n]);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Here is the output I got:

```
Before sorting the list is: 
88 56 100 2 25 
After sorting the list is: 
25 2 100 56 88
```

Comment: Aren't you going to test that comparison function of yours?

Comment: Bang! Right there :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You comparison function is incorrect. A subtraction of unsigned values can wrap the value giving an incorrect result.

The function should only compare the values:

```
int compare( const void* a , const void* b )
{
    const unsigned long ai = *( const unsigned long* )a;
    const unsigned long bi = *( const unsigned long* )b;

    if( ai < bi )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if( ai > bi )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank for the int->long correction. How do you feel about putting a space before a semicolon? :-)

Comment: Not keen on them either.  I have a script that reports on those, though, and the fix is easy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Don't you think that since the semicolon binds the least strongly it should be separated from the statement, just like for example the assignment `=` operator. Almost everybody agrees that a space should be before and after it. `int a = 5;` vs `int a = 5 ;`. From a language agnostic perspective, in the former it seems like the semicolon binds with the number.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why not? Can you elaborate?

Comment: It isn't the standard C style — look at the C standard, or K&R, or ...  In orthodox writing, you don't put spaces before full stops, commas or semicolons.  You may do as you wish on your own code; don't try it on code I'm in charge of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ahh the argument from authority. ;-)

Comment: Going with prevailing orthodoxy.  And I don't see spaces before semicolons in code very often.  I've got thirty years of experience says "it's an aberration".  You may win over the next thirty years — but I'll probably still think it wrong.  (If anything, separating the semicolon from the expression elevates its importance.  With `(a > b) ? c : d` the space around the `?` and `:` help emphasize them.  The semicolon doesn't need the emphasis.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, that makes sense.